# Python Deduplication + sum up value from dict

Tags: python, json, dictionary, duplicates

What I'm lloking to get is :

From:

```
arrayList = [{
            "value": 10,
            "name": "BBB",
            "extra": "sample"
        },{
            "value": 10,
            "name": "BBB",
        }, {
            "value": 10,
            "name": "AAA",
            "extra": "sample"
        }, {
            "value": 10,
            "name": "AAA",
        }
    ]
```

Based on the selected nameKey and valueKey, deduplication list + sum up values

So if input values will be: nameKey = "name" and valueKey = "value"
Output will be:

```
arrayList = [{
            "value": 20,
            "name": "BBB",
            "extra": "sample"
        }, {
            "value": 20,
            "name": "AAA",
            "extra": "sample"
        }
    ]
```

And if input values will be: nameKey = "extra" and valueKey = "value"
Output will be:

```
arrayList = [{
            "value": 20,
            "name": ["BBB","AAA"], <- If keys are the same, them they will be added to array
            "extra": "sample"
        },{
            "value": 10,
            "name": "BBB",
        }, {
            "value": 10,
            "name": "AAA",
        }
    ]
```

For the simplededuplication currently I'm using this: `[dict(t) for t in {tuple(d.items()) for d in arrayList }]`

But not sure how to do they way I have mentioned above, as it is sounds too complicated to make it works like this

Comment: So if the nameKey is not present, you don
't want to group those elements. And are you sure that you want such heterogenous output where some values are lists and some (with the same key) are not? What is the general logic of the addition? Add numbers and put everything else in lists? Since you could concatenate strings as well

Comment: `So if the nameKey is not present, you don 't want to group those elements.` - Yes.. Regarding keeping nameKey as array,  it is just to keep the records of summed up elements... (so nothing will be lost), in my head this is the only way to keep track of everything (unless you can suggest something else)

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure if this is what you was asking for but here is my assumption:

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict

arrayList = [
    {
        "value": 10,
        "name": "BBB",
        "extra": "sample"
    },
    {
        "value": 10,
        "name": "BBB",
    },
    {
        "value": 10,
        "name": "AAA",
        "extra": "sample"
    },
    {
        "value": 10,
        "name": "AAA",
    }
]

nameKey = "extra"
valueKey = "value"

result = defaultdict(lambda: {"name": [], valueKey: 0})

for item in arrayList:
    keyValue = item.get(nameKey)
    if isinstance(keyValue, list):
        for key in keyValue:
            result[key]["name"].append(item["name"])
            result[key][valueKey] += item[valueKey]
    elif keyValue is not None:
        result[keyValue]["name"].append(item["name"])
        result[keyValue][valueKey] += item[valueKey]

output = []
for key, value in result.items():
    output.append({**value, nameKey: key})

x = json.dumps(output, indent=4)
print(x)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

my approach in solving this simple, but depends on JsonDF package that I was working on, which gives you control over Json.

I will suggest to make a Json Template and insert to it the values, every time you insert search fot the 'key' which you want to find dublicates with, and from the Json that have that key you can get other values and compate it, and make the summtion and update the Json Values.

the code will be something like this :

```py
from JsonDF.utils.Json.Json import json

temp = Json('template', {}).objectify()

# make the normal loob and start to insert values in the temp

temp.insert('duplicates', Json('dublicate_1', {'name': name, 'value': value, 'extra': extra}))

# in every iteration

rs = temp.find_all(name)
for r in rs:
    temp.insert(name, temp.name.value + r.value)
```

this will do the trick for you

you can find the packge on [GitHub](https://github.com/OsamaElsherif/JsonDF)
or install it via `pip install JsonDF`